# Android: Scrollbar Accelerator?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollbar, long-integer, acceleration

I'm writing an Android application that contains lots of long lists and I need to accelerate scrolling somehow.  The Android Contacts application for example uses a list of letters to allow quick scrolling to a certain spot in the list ... it's not exactly what I'm looking for though.  I've seen other applications use a handle (or paddle) that appears when you start scrolling and allows you to easily drag the scrollbars to a specific location, that might be a better solution for me.

I'm wondering if anyone would have any info about either of the above methods or any other suggestions on how to accelerate scrolling through long lists (long meaning 500-750 items).

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: From the users point of view: is there a way to use fast scroll even if the developer "forgot" to use it? I really hate navigating long lists with swipe, swipe, swipe, swipe, swipe and swipe... It is a usability failure. It there an app or hack to tweak scrollers that are above certain size to use fastScroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListView
 ...
 android:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>
```

and this to "jump" in listView:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html