# How to enable fast scrolling to "EditText Field" in android application

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-scroll, android-scrollbar, android-scrolling

I am using EditText, and it has good amount of matter to scroll and read. Now my problem is, it's scrolling slow. So, i want increase it's scrolling speed. If anyone understood my problem and have solution please respond, Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Scrollbar Accelerator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563660/android-scrollbar-accelerator)

Comment: no such attribute found in EditText

Answer (score 1):

Just surround the edittext with a scrollview. I tested and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
<ListView
 ...
 android:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>
```

and this to "jump" in listView:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html

Source: [Android: Scrollbar Accelerator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563660/android-scrollbar-accelerator)

Comment: I am using EditText ans want to accelerate it's scrolling speed

Answer (score 0):

put the text box in a scrollview so that you move the textfield around and not the cursor in the text

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/YourText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</ScrollView>
```